# Always enable 'Execute UserData after next service start' for AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a server that starts and stops on a daily basis. We take AMIs of this server regularly. I want the AMIs to execute UserData on service start, but unless I remember to enable this option manually in 'Ec2 Service Properties' then any servers created from the AMI will not run the UserData script.

[image: Ec2 Service Properties - Enable UserData]

How can I set this flag so that it is always enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a config file at C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml. You can enable it there when you create the AMI.

Comment: I know how to do it, but I don't want to have to do it manually everytime I need to - I want it to always be enabled.

Comment: So in the end I modified the scheduled task 'Ec2ConfigMonitorTask' to add an extra step. This copies over the versions of 'config.xml' and 'BundleConfig.xml' that I want, to enable this setting. Not the most elegant but appears to work.